# Writing blocking operations in reactor tests with Spring and State Machine

Tags: spring, testing, junit, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm completely new to reactor programming and I'm really struggling with migrating old integration tests since upgrading to the latest Spring Boot / State Machine.
Most Integration tests have the same basic steps :

1. Call a method that returns a `Mono` and starts a state Machine and returns an object containing a generated unique `id` as well as some other infos related to the initial request.
2. With the returned object call a method that verifies if a value has been updated in the database (using the information of the object retried in step 1)
3. Poll at a fixed interval the method that checks in the database if value has changed until either the value has changed or a predefined timeout occurs.
4. Check another table in the database if another object has been updated

Below an example:

```
    @Test
    void testEndToEnd() {
      var instance = ServiceInstance.buildDefault(); 
      var updateRequest = UpdateRequest.build(instance);

      // retrieve an update Response related to the request 
      // since a unique id is generated when triggering the update request
      // before starting a stateMachine that goes through different steps        
      var updateResponse = service.updateInstance(updateRequest).block(); 

      await().alias("Check if operation was successful")
             .atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
             .pollInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
             .until(() -> expectOperationState(updateResponse, OperationState.SUCCESS))
                        
        // check if values are updated in secondary table
        assertValuesInTransaction(updateResponse);
}
```

This was working fine before but ever since the latest update where it fails with the exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-6
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
```

I saw that a good practice to test reactor methods using `StepVerifier` but I do not see how I can reproduce the part done with `Awaitability` to poll to see if the value has changed in the DB since the method that checks in the DB returns a `Mono` and not a flux that keeps sending values.

Any idea on how to accomplish this or to make the spring stack accept blocking operations?

Thanks

My current stack :

- Spring Boot 3.0.1
- Spring State Machine 3.0.1
- Spring 6
- Junit 5.9.2

Comment: If your method that checks value in db return `Mono` cant you use StepVerifier like `StepVerifier.create(service.updateInstance(updateRequest).flatMap(updateResponse -> {
            return expectOperationState(updateResponse, OperationState.SUCCESS);
        })).consumeNextWith(o -> {
            //verify the result of expectOperationState
        }).verifyComplete(); `

Comment: Hi! thanks for the input but given your example how can I make it so that the `StepVerifier` checks every x seconds to see if the status has changed in the DB because the very first time `expectOperationState` is called the value will not yet be updated in the DB, it will happen async in the `StateMachine` and can take anywhere from 5 to 100 seconds, this is why I was polling every 2 seconds with `Awaitable` any ideas?

Comment: The whole idea of reactive approach is that you do not check - the producer should emit the value as soon as it is ready or completed signal. In your case `expectOperationState` should return `Mono<SomeClass>` which when subscribed (in `flatMap` in my example) will emit the value as soon as value is changed in database. This way you do not wait - the value is emmited only when it is ready.

Comment: Thanks, could you maybe provide a small example for `expectOperationState` on how to accomplish that since I cannot really see how I can periodically check the database for a change and emit it when it has changed except by using some kind of while loop or a polling mechanism or should I try by creating a Mono from a callable which does the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as discussed in comments here is an example with comments. I used `flatMap` to subscribe to what `expectOperationState` returns. Also there is `Mono.fromCallable` used which check the value from some method and if it fails to emit anything in 3 seconds - the timeout exception is thrown. Also we could try to get rid of this `boolean` value from `expectOperationState` and refactor the code to just return `Mono<Void>` with completed signal but this basically shows how you can achieve what you want.

```
class TestStateMachine {
    @Test
    void testUntilSomeOperationCompletes() {

        final Service service = new Service();
        final UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
        StepVerifier.create(service.updateInstance(updateRequest)
                        .flatMap(updateResponse -> expectOperationState(updateResponse, OperationState.SUCCESS))
                )
                .consumeNextWith(Assertions::assertTrue)
                .verifyComplete();

    }

    private Mono<Boolean> expectOperationState(final UpdateResponse updateResponse, final OperationState success) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                    while (true) {
                        boolean isInDb = checkValueFromDb(updateResponse);
                        if (isInDb) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                //timeout if we not receive any value from callable within 3 seconds so that we do not check forever
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3));

    }

    private boolean checkValueFromDb(final UpdateResponse updateResponse) {
        return true;
    }
    
}

class Service {
    Mono<UpdateResponse> updateInstance(final UpdateRequest updateRequest) {
        return Mono.just(new UpdateResponse());
    }
}
```

Here is an example without using `Mono<Boolean>` :

```
class TestStateMachine {
    @Test
    void test() {

        final Service service = new Service();
        final UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
        StepVerifier.create(service.updateInstance(updateRequest)
                        .flatMap(updateResponse -> expectOperationState(updateResponse, OperationState.SUCCESS).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
                )
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    private Mono<Void> expectOperationState(final UpdateResponse updateResponse, final OperationState success) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                    while (true) {
                        boolean isInDb = checkValueFromDb(updateResponse);
                        if (isInDb) {
                            //return completed Mono
                            return Mono.<Void>empty();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                //timeout if we not receive any value from callable within 3 seconds so that we do not check forever
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .flatMap(objectMono -> objectMono);


    }

    private boolean checkValueFromDb(final UpdateResponse updateResponse) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks based on your example I managed to write the appropriate tests